# How to enable IME word auto-suggest in an Android EditText?

Tags: android

I have a text field and when I use the IME (the default one for Nexus One) it doesn't display the auto-suggest line on top of the soft keyboard.

Ironically there are posts here on how to prevent the auto-suggest, but in my case it's the revert, it doesn't show up and it's not clear why.

Here's my layout tag. I'm in API 8.

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/user_text"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:gravity="top"
  android:singleLine="false"
  android:inputType="textLongMessage|textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"
  android:hint="@string/errorreport_user_hint"
  android:paddingLeft="5dip"
  android:paddingRight="5dip"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah got it, I should not use the **textAutoCorrect** flag.
I thought it would ask the IME to display auto-correction, instead the doc indicates it means the editor is providing auto-corrections (I guess such as AutoCompleteEditText) and thus the IME should not display the auto-suggests.